# sorting a list of pathnames chronologically in python

Tags: python, list, file, sorting, path

So using various os commands (see below), I have a list of pathnames containing Julian Dates:

```
path = '\path\to\directory\with\files\I\want\'
    list_of_pathnames = [os.path.join(dirpath, f) 
        for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path)
        for f in fnmatch.filter(files, '*specific_string.txt')]
```

where path has files with the structure as such:

```
path = ['\path\to\directory\with\files\I\want\file_2457621_specific_string.txt',
    '\path\to\directory\with\files\I\want\file_2457632_specific_string.txt',
    '\path\to\directory\with\files\I\want\file_2457622_specific_string.txt']
```

What are some ways to organize these julian dates in chronological order from oldest (2457621) to most recent (2457632)?

Comment: Uh... `path.sort()`?

Comment: What have you tried/researched?

Comment: @StefanPochmann That would return the *Lexicographical* order without specifying the `key`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis So what? That's equivalent here, no?

Comment: @StefanPochmann : that will work if the file name is same until the numbers start for each one. Otherwise for something like `a2` and  `b1` , it won't.

Comment: The answer lies in using regex and using it to sort.

Comment: Have you tried path = sorted(path) ? . It should give you proper output as the rest of the string is same.

Comment: Stefan, path.sort() returns "None" but path=sorted(path) does exactly what I want. Thanks Sam!

Comment: @DaxFeliz Huh? `path=sorted(path)` doesn't return anything. So is `path.sort()` bad for you because it *does* return something (`None`)? Can't you just ignore that like you're supposed to? In what way is `path=sorted(path)` better for you than `path.sort()`? And under Ev.Kounis's answer you said `path.sort` does work for you, even though their version of course also returns `None`. You're quite contradictory.

Comment: I'm just reporting my outputs, man. path.sort() without any arguments produced an output of "None". Whereas Ev's suggestion below WITH arguments produced a alphanumerically sorted list. I was premature in saying the path = sorted(path) worked as it ordered my pathnames within a directory but not recursively (for subdirectories, which I did not request for so that's on me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go with *alphanumeric* order instead of *lexicographical*, you have to *"get"* the integers out of the strings and sort based on them.

One way to do it would be the following:

```
import os
path = [r'\path\to\directory\with\files\I\want\file_2457621_specific_string.txt',
        r'\path\to\directory\with\files\I\want\file_2457632_specific_string.txt',
        r'\path\to\directory\with\files\I\want\file_2457622_specific_string.txt']

path.sort(key=lambda x: int(os.path.basename(x).split('_')[1]))
```

Just FYI, if my `regex` skills were any good I would do it with regex though.

As the comments say, in your example, there is no difference, but for instance, these two:

```
path = [r'\path\file_22_specific_string.txt', r'\path\file_200_specific_string.txt']
```

would produce different results depending on whether the numeric characters are treated as strings or numbers.

Comment: Do you think they have dates from thousands of years ago?

Comment: @StefanPochmann You never know.. Or at least I never do. They do seem to have some from the future `'2457622'`

Comment: Huh? No. That date is from **last year**.

Comment: More precisely it's August 21, 2016. And the seven-digits dates range from about 4000 years ago to over 20000 years into the future. So I find it very reasonable to assume that lexicographical order suffices.

Comment: Btw, why "alphanumeric" instead of "numeric"?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Why don't you write an answer with all those interesting details? Your first and second to last comment don't agree by the way.

Comment: I'm waiting (so far in vain) for the OP to clarify why they don't just do `path.sort()`.

Comment: What do you mean? What doesn't agree?

Comment: @StefanPochmann *"Do you think they have dates from **thousands of years ago**?"* with *"And the seven-digits dates range from about **4000** years ago to over 20000 years into the future"*. Emphasis mine.

Comment: Those don't disagree. The first one btw refers to your dates 22 and 200.

Comment: Do you think 4000 isn't thousands?

Comment: Irgendwie reden wir uns grad vorbei. Vergiss es einfach.